# java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY Error while converting POJO to HasMap<String,String> using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class POJOClass {
    @NonNull
    private List<String> states;

    @NonNull
    private String country;

    @NonNull
    private String capital;

    public Map<String,String> convertToMap() {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>> hashMapType
                = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, String>>() {};
        return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(this, hashMapType);
    }
}
```

i am trying to convert an instance of the above class into a `HashMap<String,String>` using instance.convertToMap(), but this fails with error

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["states"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._convert(ObjectMapper.java:3605)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3546)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.convertValue(ObjectMapper.java:3534)
```

I believe this is because of the List when deserialising to map isnt getting converted to String.

Is there a way where i can convert a POJO to `Map<String,String>` and i dont want a type of `Map<String, Object>` ?

Comment: You need to past in the relevant json.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more ? I am trying to convert an instance of the class to the Map<String,String> without me dealing directly with the json of it.

Comment: what output are you expecting?  a List doesn't naturally convert into a Map irrespective of the mechanism

Comment: I need the output of the method convertToMap be a HasMap<String,String> . I need the list to be converted into a string and be stored in the HasMap<String,string>

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do the `TypeReference` of type `Map<String, String>` since `states` is not a string, but a list, so you can change the `TypeReference` into `Map<String,Object>` and this should over even if you have a list or if you want in the future to add a complex object

```
public Map<String, String> convertToMap() {
    TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> hashMapType = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
    };
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(this, hashMapType);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You can still leave the `Map<String, String>` as the return type of the method `convertToMap()`

Full example:

```
@Builder
@Getter
public class POJOClass {
    @NonNull
    private List<String> states;

    @NonNull
    private String country;

    @NonNull
    private String capital;

    public Map<String, String> convertToMap() {
        TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> hashMapType = new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {
        };
        return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(this, hashMapType);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        POJOClass pojoClass = new POJOClass(Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c"), "England", "London");
        System.out.println(pojoClass.convertToMap());
    }
}
```

Comment: if I have the type reference as map<string,object> . then wouldn't the map returned by the convertToMap method also be a HashMap<String,Object> ?

Comment: but there is a constraint that i need to return a HashMap<String, String> irrespective of the type of fields the POJOClass has. So, is there any way i can return a HashMap<String, String> class, like some how can i convert the list to string while creating the HashMap ?

Comment: @achut1993, as you can see, I am returning Map<String, String>. I am just doing the convert to Map<String, Object> only when doing the TypeReference. This works fine. I will update my answer to show you an example

Comment: This doesnt work as if you do pojoClass.convertToMap().get("states") it is a List not String.

Comment: @achut1993 `List<String> states = Collections.singletonList(pojoClass.convertToMap().get("states"));`

Comment: I dont need the List. What i am trying to achieve here is a Map<String,String> where each value is a String irrespective of the actual type of the field earlier in POJO. Like the type of pojoClass.convertToMap().get("states") in the above example should come out as a String, but with the approach you have stated in your answer it is a List, but i want it to be a stringified list.

Comment: Sorry, but I think the problem that you are facing is different from what the initial problem

Comment: if you see my code in the question and the error "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY" I was trying to get a Map<String,String> out of the POJO. The method you have suggested was returning Map<String,Object> even thought your code was typecasting it to Map<String,String>. So, is there a way where i can convert my POJO to Map<String,String> ?